Mutual information between randomly permuted variables
I am trying to understand how to calculate the mutual information between two variables which have nonzero conditional mutual information (when conditioned on a third variable) but (I believe) zero mutual information when not conditioned on the third variable.
Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a set of messages which Alice can send. Suppose Alice selects a message $x_i\in\mathcal{X}$ with probability $p_i$ from a set of $N$ possible messages. Call this random variable $X$.
Now imagine the set of $N!$ permutations over the set $\mathcal{X}$. Let $Q$ be a random variable which selects (with equal probability) a random permutation which is applied to $X$.
Suppose this permuted message is then passed on to Bob. Let $Y\in\mathcal{X}$ be the random variable which corresponds to the result of applying the permutation determined by $Q$ to Alice's original message $X$. If $N$ is large, then there is a large probability that the message Bob receives is different to the one Alice sent.
I am interested in calculating the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, both conditional on $Q$ and unconditional. Intuitively, I can see that the unconditional mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ is zero, because randomly permuting $X$ is the same as a just using a new random variable. But if the permutation $Q$ is known, then Bob can work out with certainty which message Alice sent. This would suggest that the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ is high, if conditioned on $Q$. However, I am not sure how to prove both conditional and unconditional mutual informations and would appreciate help.
Sometimes, for questions where the answer is intuitive, people can provide proofs which work but also rely on the user to see in advance what the answer is. If possible, I would appreciate a proof/derivation which works through the problem and each step makes sense in isolation even if one does not `see' in advance where it is going. Thanks!

Here's how I understood the question: $X$ is sampled from $[1:N]$ according to some given law $p$. $Q$ is a random permutation on $[1:N],$ drawn uniformly at random and independently of $X$. $Y = Q(X)$, and you want to know $I(X;Y)$ and $I(X;Y|Q)$. All of your intuitions about this are fine, it's just a question of writing them down properly.
To figure out $I(X;Y)$, we need to understand the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Now observe that for any pair $(x,y)$, there are $(N-1)!$ permutations sending $x$ to $y$. Since $Q$ is chosen independently of $X,$ it follows that for any pair $(x,y),$ $$P(Y = y|X = x) = P( Q(x) = y|X = x) = P(Q(x) = y) = 1/N.$$ Importantly, this does not depend on the value of $x$, so $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which immediately yields $I(X;Y) = 0$.
On the other hand, knowing both $Y$ and $Q$ determines $X$, since we could invert the permutation to compute $X = Q^{-1}(Y).$ This means that $H(X|Q,Y) = 0$. But $X$ and $Q$ are independent, so we know that $H(X|Q) = H(X)$. It follows that $$ I(X;Y|Q) = H(X|Q) - H(X|Q,Y) = H(X) - 0 = H(X).$$
